# jQuery - IE ONLY css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

Is it possible to use

```
var script = document.createElement('link');
script.href = 'theme/style/ie/manageleads.css';
script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
script.type = 'text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

and for it to only be active if the browser is IE8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Note that IE8 claims to be 7 in Compatibility View.

```
if ($.browser == 'msie' && (parseInt($.browser.version) == 8 || parseInt($.browser.version) == 7))
{
    // Do something IE8-only in here
}
```

Comment: "$.browser == 'msie'" did not work for me. instead I used "$.browser.msie" - worked like a charm. :)

Comment: @AlexZak Yes, jQuery changed the `toString()` of `$.browser` as it used to return the "name" of the browser. It's also worth nothing that as of jQuery 1.9, `$.browser` is **removed**, and no longer works - see the original link in my answer to jQuery.browser for more details

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be conditional CSS, but since you asked for jQuery, here ya go.

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 8) {
  $('<link />', {
    href: 'theme/style/ie/manageleads.css',
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css'
  }).appendTo('head');
}
```

If that doesn't work, let me know. You might need to use 'document.createStylesheet' instead.

Comment: `$.browser.version` is likely to return something like `8.2256.4382`, so you need to use (ideally) `parseInt` to just get the major version number back out of it.

Comment: Good call, I didn't notice that.